# How do I access a variable in a struct within a 2d array inside of another struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am working on an assignment for my class and I don't understand how I am supposed to access the variable inside a game_piece struct. I need to check to see if it is the default assignment or not, but am confused about how to do so.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct game_piece
{
    char label[30];
};

struct game_board
{
    struct game_piece **board;
};

void game_piece_init_default(struct game_piece *piece)
// This function initializes a game piece with the default label.
{
    strcpy(*piece->label, "SSS");
}

void game_piece_init(struct game_piece *piece, char *new_label)
// This function initializes a game piece with a specified label.
{
    strcpy(*piece->label, new_label);
}

char *game_piece_get_label(struct game_piece *piece)
// This function returns the label of a game piece.
{
    return *piece->label;
}

int game_board_add_piece(struct game_board *game_board, struct game_piece *piece, int row, int col)
{
    if (game_board_is_space_valid(game_board, row, col))
    {
        if (strcmp((game_board->board[row][col])->label, "SSS")) // Error here
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: The expression `*piece->label` is the same as `piece->label[0]`. Which is likely not what you want.

Comment: And `game_board->board[row][col]` is an `game_piece` *object*, not a pointer to a `game_piece` object. So the arrow operator is wrong. E.g. `game_board->board[row][col]->label` should be `game_board->board[row][col].label`.

Comment: Lastly please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). When asking questions about build errors, always include the actual errors in your question. Copy-pasted (as text) in full and complete.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are missing the understanding how to work with pointers (nothing to shame on as you are probably a beginner if this is a class assignment).
The `->` is dereferencing, but your `game_board` apparently does not have pointers to instances of `game_piece`, but the content directly.
Because of that, you have to change it to a `.`.

Also, as both `->` and the prefix `*` are dereferencing, this will not work. I recommend to remove the `*`s at the specific points.

Beyond your question:

- `strcpy` would create a buffer overflow, if your `new_label` at initialization is longer than 30 characters, including the terminating `\0`. I recommend to switch to `strncpy` to limit this to the size of the target array, but also have some error handling for the case the caller provides a too long string.
- Your nested `if` does not always have a defined `return` value, which is even mourned by `gcc` in default settings.
- Instead of using `int`, modern C has a `bool` datatype, which is not really type safe, but better than nothing.

As you did not provide a `main`, to have a minimally running example except your issue, I was not able to test all this.
The code I had at the end was:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct game_piece
{
    char label[30];
};

struct game_board
{
    struct game_piece **board;
};

void game_piece_init_default(struct game_piece *piece)
// This function initializes a game piece with the default label.
{
    strcpy(piece->label, "SSS");
}

void game_piece_init(struct game_piece *piece, char *new_label)
// This function initializes a game piece with a specified label.
{
    strcpy(piece->label, new_label);
}

char *game_piece_get_label(struct game_piece *piece)
// This function returns the label of a game piece.
{
    return piece->label;
}

int game_board_is_space_valid(struct game_board *game_board, int row, int col)
{
  return 1;
}

int game_board_add_piece(struct game_board *game_board, struct game_piece *piece, int row, int col)
{
    if (game_board_is_space_valid(game_board, row, col))
    {
        if (strcmp((game_board->board[row][col]).label, "SSS"))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: be aware of trying to use \* in your answer; it will be used for formatting (turned your text into *italics*) if you don't backslash-cancel it

Answer (score 0):

I think the type of game_piece[][] is game_piece *, but the type of game_board is game_piece **.